# How to reset polymer iron-autogrow-textarea or paper-textarea through it's methods?

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I am able to clear iron-autogrow-textarea by setting the value to empty string but I am unable to clear the newline or reset it. I am using event on keycode enter which works but leaves this new line and no way I can find a way to reset the iron-autogrow-textarea to its initial state.

If anything similar can be done with paper-textarea, I can use that instead.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below information is written in its own page, so you need to update with : `ironAutogrowTextarea.value`

> Imperatively updating ironAutogrowTextarea.value will update the
>   textarea.value

instead `ironAutogrowTextarea.textarea.value`

> Imperatively updating ironAutogrowTextarea.textarea.value will update
>   the display, but not update the internal value

Written its demo link: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-autogrow-textarea/demo/demo/index.html